# Icon DataTemplate for Icon MenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I create some graphics for menuitem.icon.

```html
<DataTemplate x:Key="navigation_arrow">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>
            <Canvas>
                 <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="20"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then I try use this template for menuitem.icon

```html
<MenuItem Header="" Icon="{Binding navigation_arrow}"/>
```

But it is empty menuitem. If I insert template code in MenuItem.Icon all work good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: your binding is wrong. You must use this key as `{DynamicResource navigation_arrow}` or `{StaticResource navigation_arrow}`.

But It's not working. Your icon will be "System.Windows.DataTemplate" string, in this case.

`DataTemplate` means "It will apply a template for a data". You haven't got Data for Icon, so it cannot apply template for this.

You have to add concrete item as icon (like you mentioned) or create a style for it:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                 <Grid>
                     <Canvas>
                         <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="20"/>
                     </Canvas>
                 </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but the fancy way is:

- [use `DrawingBrush` from resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749021(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Your link is empty, shows information: This topic is no longer available

Comment: Updated - This topic is missing from MSDN for .NET 4.5 (I have no clue why)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *ContentControl*:

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource navigation_arrow}"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```